# How to submit a form after you're done typing? (JavaScript async)

Tags: javascript

I need to make a form submit after the user has stopped typing for lets say half a second.

You should maintain the input focused and if you type a few more characters it should still resume submitting.

I would prefer ***vanilla JS*** but ***jQuery*** will do as well.

I have tried using a `onKeydown` event to set a timeout of half a second, then I used a `preventDefault()` followed by a `form.submit()`

```js
let searchText = document.getElementById('search_input');
searchText.onkeypress = function(e) {
  //alert("key down");

  var event = e || window.event;
  var charCode = event.which || event.keycode;

  if (charCode == '13') {
    fnFillGrid();

    return false;
  }
}

function fnFillGrid() {
  console.log('Lala');
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  Search: <input id="search_input" type="search" name="q">
</form>
```

I would like the user to be able to type in the input and one second after they finish typing to submit the search. The focus blur should remain on the input so they can continue typing/searching.

Comment: I don't see any attempt at a submit here. I would also note that `KeyboardEvent.which` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

Comment: Sorry I tried it on jsfiddle and didnt get a chance to save it. This code snippet is the old code that I have to update.

Comment: could you please add your jsfiddle?

Comment: It's `keyCode`, not  `keycode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to capture the time between last key typed and the your specific waiting period. In this case, the POST request is executed after 1 second of no typing. This would be a real example (posting to `jsonplaceholder` to mock the POST request). You can check your network tab (in dev tools) to watch it.

It should also be called out here that `KeyboardEvent.which` is deprecated (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which)

```js
const postMessage = async (message) => {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: 'title',
        body: message,
        userId: 1
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    });
    return response.json();
}

let time = null;
const textBox = document.getElementById('myTextbox');
textBox.addEventListener('keyup', async (e) => {
  time = new Date().getTime();
  setTimeout( async () => {
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    const timeDiff = currentTime - time;
    if (timeDiff >= 1000) {
     const response = await postMessage(textBox.value);
        console.log('response', response);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myTextbox" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This will fire `onkeyup`, which I've found to be the best way to initiate auto searches like this:

```js
let searchText = document.getElementById('search_input');
searchText.addEventListener("keyup", search);

let timeout = null;

function search() {
  if (timeout) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
  
  timeout = setTimeout(function () { fnFillGrid(); }, 500);
}

function fnFillGrid() {
  console.log('Lala');
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  Search: <input id="search_input" type="search" name="q">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution is based on two ideas:

1. Capture the keys
2. After the user stop typing we send an `async` POST request.

For our first goal, we gonna use the `addEventListener` and listen for `keyup` event. This event occurs when the user releases a key on the keyboard.

For the second goal, we need to capture the time between last `keyup` event and compare it with the `WAITING_TIME` constant, for this example 500 ms.

Also, we gonna use an `async function` declaration to define the `fnFillGrid` asynchronous function. This returns an `AsyncFunction` object as a `Promise` which will be resolved with the value returned by the `async function`, or rejected with an uncaught exception thrown from within the `async function`. The `fnFillGrid` will also implements a `fetch()` method, which allows us to make network requests similar to `XMLHttpRequest`. The main difference is that the `fetch()` method uses `Promises`, which enables a simpler and cleaner API, avoiding callback hell and having to remember the complex API of `XMLHttpRequest`.

Now, we can call the `await()` operator to wait for the response `Promise`.

Here you have a functional snippet:

```js
const WAITING_TIME = 500;
let startTime;
let searchText = document.getElementById('search_input');
searchText.addEventListener('keyup', async(e) => {
  startTime = new Date().getTime();
  setTimeout(async() => {
    let currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    let timeDiff = currentTime - startTime;
    if (timeDiff >= WAITING_TIME) {
      const response = await fnFillGrid(searchText.value);
      console.log('response', response);
    }
  }, WAITING_TIME);
});

async function fnFillGrid(message) {
  let result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: message,
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
  });
  
  return result.json();
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  Search: <input id="search_input" type="search" name="q">
</form>
```